# Where should I write the javaDoc comments?

Tags: java

I'm creating the javadoc of my project, but i'm not sure where should i write it.
I have all the javaDoc implemented in my interfaces. And I have classes implementing these interfaces (and not adding extra-methods). So, Is there any command to copy the javadoc from the interfaces to my classes? Or should i Copy-paste from my interfaces to the implementation?

Comment: It should be sufficient to write the documentation at the interface-methods. The methods should then be displayed as "inherited" in the implementig classes, linking to the javaDoc-Page of the interface.

Comment: I would include implementation documentation only if the implementations has any notable characteristics outside of the contract.